# Sending data to client "connection refused"

Tags: c#, python, multithreading, sockets, server

since I can't solve this problem I thought about to post it. My setup:

- Server/Client: udp, non-blocking
- Server is written in Python
- Client is written in C#
- I'm using Threads for Listening

---

### Server

How I create a the socket:

```
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 8888 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setblocking(False)

# Die socket Adresse bei Windows setzt sich aus dem Host und der IP zusammen.
sockAddress = (HOST, PORT)

# Bindet den Socket an die gewünschte Adresse
sock.bind(sockAddress)
```

My listener thread looks like this (short version):

```
while(globals.stopListener == False):
    try:
        dataPackage, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.error as e:
        if e.errno == 10035:
            t.sleep(0.1)
            continue
    except Exception as e:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Unknown Error !"
        print >>sys.stderr, e
        break

    if dataPackage:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Packet erhalten: " + dataPackage
        header = int(dataPackage[0])
        time = dataPackage[1:6+1]
        package = dataPackage[7:]

        if header == 0:
            # -------------------- LOGIN --------------------------
            isValid = Login.validateLogin(dataPackage)

            if isValid:
                sock.sendto("\nWilkommen auf dem Server "+name, address)
                globals.players.append(address)
                print >>sys.stderr, "Player: " + len(globals.players)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, "Sended wrong PW or NAME"
                sock.sendto("Falsche Login Daten!", address)#, address)
```

sendto produces the error:
***ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte'))***

I've tried already:

- Opened my port 8888, forward to my IP (but I think this is only neccassary if I would use the client on another computer)
- disabled my firewall
- instead of using 0.0.0.0 I used localhost (just in case)

---

### Client

Socket connection:

```
public class SocketManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private byte[] _recData = new byte[1024];
    private bool _stopListen = false;
    private const string HOST = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"; <-- my local ip 192....
    private const int PORT = 8888;
    private Socket _sock;
    public static SocketManager socketHandler { get; private set; }
    public IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(SocketManager.HOST), SocketManager.PORT);
    public EndPoint rec_endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    this._sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    this._sock.Connect(endpoint);
    this._sock.Blocking = false;
```

short version of the listener (also a new thread):

```
public void startListen()
{
    byte[] recData = new byte[1024];
    IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
    EndPoint senderRemote = (EndPoint)sender;

    while (!this._stop)
    {
        try
        {
            this.sock.ReceiveFrom(recData, ref senderRemote);//, ref endpoint);.......
```

I hope my style is readable.

*Regards,*

***Sens4***

---

**Edit1**: I've quickly wrote the client in python ... And the same error occured. -.-"

**Edit2**: Now I've checked with netstat, if the port of the client is listening and it isn't. But I think he should listen :O

```
  netstat -a -p UDP (shortended)

  Aktive Verbindungen (active connections)
  Proto  Lokale Adresse         Remoteadresse          Status
  UDP    0.0.0.0:8888           *:*      <---- my server
```

I think my client should also be shown right ?
I've received the current port and IP of the client with `sock.getsockname()`, but it is not shown.

Comment: Both of them are listening to the same port on the same interface?

Comment: I think so, it is very strange because, my client can send a package to the server. The server receives the package (also of course the address from the client)  but can't send a message back.

Comment: Did you spawn both, client and server, on the same machine, for testing?

Comment: Of course. I really don't get it, why the server can receives packages but he fails if he tries to send one.

Comment: Try binding your ports to different IPs. i.e. bind the server to localhost (127.0.0.1:8888) and your client to 192.168.0.1:8888. When you use 0.0.0.0, it will bind to all available interfaces and I don't think you can have your python script listen to the same port on all interfaces, while your client does the same. Or run them on different computers (or a virtual machine)